# Rotating an 3D object around it's y-axis in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I just started exploring three.js and have been trying to adapt a project I found.

I would like to know if it would be possible to have the globe object rotate around it's y-axis with minor additions to the code or whether it has to be rewritten from the ground up.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var width = canvas.offsetWidth,
height = canvas.offsetHeight;

var colors = [
new THREE.Color(0xac1122),
new THREE.Color(0x96789f),
new THREE.Color(0x535353)];

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
canvas: canvas,
antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 2 : 1);
renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.params.Points.threshold = 6;


var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, width / height, 0.1, 2000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 350);

var galaxy = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(galaxy);

// Create dots
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = "";
var dotTexture = loader.load("img/dotTexture.png");
var dotsAmount = 3000;
var dotsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var positions = new Float32Array(dotsAmount * 3);

var sizes = new Float32Array(dotsAmount);
var colorsAttribute = new Float32Array(dotsAmount * 3);
for (var i = 0; i < dotsAmount; i++) {
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

vector.color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
vector.theta = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
vector.phi =
    (1 - Math.sqrt(Math.random())) *
    Math.PI /
    2 *
    (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);

vector.x = Math.cos(vector.theta) * Math.cos(vector.phi);
vector.y = Math.sin(vector.phi);
vector.z = Math.sin(vector.theta) * Math.cos(vector.phi);
vector.multiplyScalar(120 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 5);
vector.scaleX = 5;

if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    moveDot(vector, i);
}
dotsGeometry.vertices.push(vector);
vector.toArray(positions, i * 3);
colors[vector.color].toArray(colorsAttribute, i*3);
sizes[i] = 5;
}

function moveDot(vector, index) {
    var tempVector = vector.clone();
    tempVector.multiplyScalar((Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.2 + 1);
    TweenMax.to(vector, Math.random() * 3 + 3, {
        x: tempVector.x,
        y: tempVector.y,
        z: tempVector.z,
        yoyo: true,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: -Math.random() * 3,
        ease: Power0.easeNone,
        onUpdate: function () {
            attributePositions.array[index*3] = vector.x;
            attributePositions.array[index*3+1] = vector.y;
            attributePositions.array[index*3+2] = vector.z;
        }
    });
}

var bufferWrapGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var attributePositions = new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3);
bufferWrapGeom.addAttribute('position', attributePositions);
var attributeSizes = new THREE.BufferAttribute(sizes, 1);
bufferWrapGeom.addAttribute('size', attributeSizes);
var attributeColors = new THREE.BufferAttribute(colorsAttribute, 3);
bufferWrapGeom.addAttribute('color', attributeColors);
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
uniforms: {
    texture: {
        value: dotTexture
    }
},
vertexShader: document.getElementById("wrapVertexShader").textContent,
fragmentShader: document.getElementById("wrapFragmentShader").textContent,
transparent:true 
});
var wrap = new THREE.Points(bufferWrapGeom, shaderMaterial);
scene.add(wrap);

// Create white segments
var segmentsGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
var segmentsMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
color: 0xffffff,
transparent: true,
opacity: 0.3,
vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});
for (i = dotsGeometry.vertices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
vector = dotsGeometry.vertices[i];
for (var j = dotsGeometry.vertices.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (i !== j && vector.distanceTo(dotsGeometry.vertices[j]) < 12) {
        segmentsGeom.vertices.push(vector);
        segmentsGeom.vertices.push(dotsGeometry.vertices[j]);
        segmentsGeom.colors.push(colors[vector.color]);
        segmentsGeom.colors.push(colors[vector.color]);
    }
}
}
var segments = new THREE.LineSegments(segmentsGeom, segmentsMat);
galaxy.add(segments);

var hovered = [];
var prevHovered = [];
function render(a) {
     var i;
dotsGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
segmentsGeom.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects([wrap]);
hovered = [];
if (intersections.length) {
    for(i = 0; i < intersections.length; i++) {
        var index = intersections[i].index;
        hovered.push(index);
        if (prevHovered.indexOf(index) === -1) {
            onDotHover(index);
        }
     }
}
for(i = 0; i < prevHovered.length; i++){
    if(hovered.indexOf(prevHovered[i]) === -1){
        mouseOut(prevHovered[i]);
    }
}
prevHovered = hovered.slice(0);
attributeSizes.needsUpdate = true;
attributePositions.needsUpdate = true;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onDotHover(index) {
dotsGeometry.vertices[index].tl = new TimelineMax();
dotsGeometry.vertices[index].tl.to(dotsGeometry.vertices[index], 1, {
    scaleX: 10,
    ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(2, 0.2),
    onUpdate: function() {
        attributeSizes.array[index] = dotsGeometry.vertices[index].scaleX;
    }
});
}

function mouseOut(index) {
dotsGeometry.vertices[index].tl.to(dotsGeometry.vertices[index], 0.4, {
    scaleX: 5,
    ease: Power2.easeOut,
    onUpdate: function() {
        attributeSizes.array[index] = dotsGeometry.vertices[index].scaleX;
    }
});
}

function onResize() {
canvas.style.width = '';
canvas.style.height = '';
width = canvas.offsetWidth;
height = canvas.offsetHeight;
camera.aspect = width / height;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(-100,-100);
function onMouseMove(e) {
var canvasBounding = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
mouse.x = ((e.clientX - canvasBounding.left) / width) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = -((e.clientY - canvasBounding.top) / height) * 2 + 1;
}

TweenMax.ticker.addEventListener("tick", render);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
var resizeTm;
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
resizeTm = clearTimeout(resizeTm);
resizeTm = setTimeout(onResize, 200);
});
```

Codepen here - https://codepen.io/quickwaste/pen/PaGPdw

Thanks.

(A stretch goal would be to have the camera move in response to mouse movement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add  `galaxy.rotateY(0.005 * Math.PI);` to `render()`, right before `renderer.render(scene, camera)` call, like this:

```
// pulled from the CodePen
function render(a) {

    // ... omitted for brevity

    prevHovered = hovered.slice(0);
    attributeSizes.needsUpdate = true;
    attributePositions.needsUpdate = true;

    galaxy.rotateY(0.005 * Math.PI);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I used a multiplier of 0.005 to give the globe a nice, lazy spin.

The 'galaxy' object is a `THREE.Group`, a wrapper of sorts for collections of `THREE.Object3D` objects. The `Object3D` has all sorts of nifty functions to help rotate, translate, and transform 3D objects. The [`rotateY()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D.rotateY) will spin the model around its local y-axis.

Comment: The circles (nodes) become detached from the apexes of the vectors once the globe it set to rotate. I suspect that might be complex to fix?